# Ubuntu as router with netplan & dnsmasq - can't reach websites

Tags: networking, iptables, netplan, router

I have setup Ubuntu 22.04 LTS as a router for the following scenario:

```
Client (192.168.222.100) <--> Switch <--> Ubuntu Router eth0 (192.168.222.1) <--> Ubuntu Router enx2887ba778049 (192.168.178.111) <--> WAN Router (192.168.178.1) <--> Internet
```

This is my netplan config:

```
network:
    ethernets:
        eth0:
            dhcp4: false
        enx2887ba778049:
            dhcp4: true
            optional: true
    bridges:
        br0:
            interfaces:
                - eth0
            addresses:
                - 192.168.222.1/24
            nameservers:
                addresses: [8.8.8.8]
                search: []
            optional: true
    version: 2
```

This is my dnsmasq config:

```
port=53

domain-needed
bogus-priv
strict-order

except-interface=enx2887ba778049

expand-hosts
domain=example.com

dhcp-range=192.168.222.50,192.168.222.240,255.255.255.0,24h
dhcp-option=option:router,192.168.222.1
dhcp-option=option:dns-server,192.168.222.1
dhcp-option=option:netmask,255.255.255.0
```

From my client, web URLs get resolved:

```
dig google.com        

; <<>> DiG 9.10.6 <<>> google.com
;; global options: +cmd
;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NOERROR, id: 47720
;; flags: qr rd ra; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 1, AUTHORITY: 0, ADDITIONAL: 1

;; OPT PSEUDOSECTION:
; EDNS: version: 0, flags:; udp: 512
;; QUESTION SECTION:
;google.com.            IN  A

;; ANSWER SECTION:
google.com.     269 IN  A   142.250.74.206
```

However, the problem is that I cannot reach them:

```
ping google.com
PING google.com (142.250.74.206): 56 data bytes
Request timeout for icmp_seq 0
Request timeout for icmp_seq 1
```

I think I have to do something with iptables, but the following failed:

```
sudo iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o enx2887ba778049 -j MASQUERADE
sudo iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o eth0 -j MASQUERADE
```

Any ideas what I need to do to get from the client to the internet?

Comment: Hi @Sebastian Can the client ping the WAN Router? I guess no. Please remove the MASQUERADE rule on eth0. This rule is not needed, but I'm not sure this fixes your issue.

Comment: Thanks. Removing the MASQUERADE did not solve the issue, and as you guessed correctly, the WAN router cannot be pinged from the client.

Comment: 1) ipforwarding should be enabled at more than 1 interface. any way please check `cat /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward` should be 1. 2) check your iptables rules.  reset counter with `iptables -Z` and look at the FORWARD Chain `iptables -xvnL FORWARD`

Comment: Thanks, the ip_forward thing was it!

`/etc/sysctl.conf` --> `net.ipv4.ip_forward=1`

I still need `sudo iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o enx2887ba778049 -j MASQUERADE`.